# How to filter backward joins?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a model `Article` and several `ArticleDescription` (one for each language).

```
class Article(models.Model):
    articleid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.articleid)


class ArticleDescription(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lang = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='en', blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('article', 'lang')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.description)
```

I am struggling now how to make a join to select only the current language's description in my template.

I use this code to get my articles:

```
c = models.Article.objects.all().order_by('articleid')
```

In `c`, I have my `ArticleDescriptions` available in my template like this:

```
{% for b in c %}
    {{ b.articledescription_set.all }}
{% endfor %}
```

But, I do not want all the descriptions, just the one for the current language. So I am looking for something like:

```
c = models.Article.objects.all().join(ArticleDescription, lang=curlang).order_by('articleid')
```

and then I can use the description like this in my template:

```
{% for b in c %}
    {{ b.articledescription.description }}
{% endfor %}
```

But, I have no idea how to do this, or where to look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) and a custom Prefetch object. This needs to be done in the view.

```
desc = ArticleDescription.objects.filter(lang=curlang)
c = models.Article.objects.all().order_by('articleid').prefetch_related(Prefetch('articledescription_set', queryset=desc, to_attr='filtered_descriptions'))
```

Now you can do:

```
{% for b in c %}
    {{ b.filtered_descriptions }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks it works, but it should be noted that `b.filtered_descriptions` is an array of `ArticleDescription`.

Comment: Yes, isn't that what you want?

Comment: Yes, it is good. In this case I know for a fact it is only one hit, though. Another small question, can I use the `filtered_descriptions` also in a `Q` object in the `filter`?